# Disable escaping symbols in Apache Axis client

Tags: java, xml, web-services, escaping, axis

I'm working on creating axis client for some web-service that I was provided. Service generates PDF file from received XML, so I need to pass "pure" xml as one of parameters to service. The problem is, like it seems, Axis performs escaping symbols "<" and ">". So I get exception from service

> net.homecredit.apps.common.api.ServiceException: java.rmi.RemoteException: ; nested exception is:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXException: No deserializer for {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType

What I should send:

```
<ns1:parameter name="xml" xsi:type="ns1:ParameterType">
    <abc><id>124240</id><text>text</text></abc>
</<ns1:parameter>
```

In Axis method Call # invoke I see:

```
<ns1:parameter name="xml" xsi:type="ns1:ParameterType">
    &lt;abc&gt;&lt;id&gt;124240&lt;/id&gt;&lt;text&gt;text&lt;/text&gt;&lt;/abc&gt;
</<ns1:parameter>
```

How can I disable it?

Comment: May be it will be useful for someone. Axis (and Spring-WS too) performs escaping special characters in request because it treats parameter like a string according to definition in wsdl/xsd. If type defined with <simpleContent> element then it is supposed to contain string content. You have to change simpleContent definition to complexContent (may be with mixed="true" attribute).